# Python/PyODBC Connect to SQL Server 2008 DB by IP with Trusted Connection

Tags: python, sql-server-2008, pyodbc

If this has been asked, I apologize in advance, I couldn't find the right answer, although I've found similar questions.

I'm trying to connect to a SQL Server 2008 DB by using it's IP / Port using trusted connection.

One additional point of complexity is: The database is outside of the US and usually we log in via Citrix.  After logging into citrix, it uses our windows credentials (not sure if that impacts the issue).

I have tried several different types of connection strings

Driver=SQL Server 
Driver=SQL Native Client
Driver=SQL Server Native Client 10.0

I've also tried differen't formats of including the port, as well as messing with the Network Library when using the IP route.

I was hoping someone could help me understand 2 things.

1) (Most importantly) How do I figure out how to properly connect without simple trial and error.  I tried checking connectionstrings.com but that didn't really help all that much.  I haven't been able to find anything online.

2) If someone can help me out with connection string.

Here's an example of what I'm doing:

```
cn = pyodbc.connect(r'DRIVER={SQL Native Client};Server=1.1.3.4,1234;Network    Library=DBMSSOCN;Initial Catalog=Test;UID=DOM\me;Pwd=pass')
```

Any help/guidance is much appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You don't need to specify a user or password if you want to use a trusted connection, instead use the paramater `Trusted_Connection=yes`. See [here](http://code.google.com/p/pyodbc/wiki/ConnectionStrings#Security) for the documentation.

Something like this has worked for me in the past:

```
cn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL Native Client};
                     Server=1.1.3.4; DATABASE=mydb; 
                     Trusted_Connection=yes;')
```

Comment: Hi Matti,  apologies for not getting back sooner.  I've been swamped with issues and haven't had a chance to come back to the code just yet.  I'll post as soon as I have a moment.  Thank you for your time, even looking into it.

Comment: Another reason it might not be working is the format of the IP address format - have you tried using a colon instead of a comma to separate the port number?

Answer (score -5):

Find [here](http://ofers-python-articles.pythonblogs.com/227_ofers_python_articles/archive/1299_using_pythons_pyodbc_with_microsoft_sql_server_and_sql_server_data_tools_for_visual_studio.html) some explanation, relevant links, and sample code.

Comment: You generally don't want to provide a link as an SO answer, because most of the time the link will be outdated and not working in future. This actually happens with your link. It does not work.