# SQL Server Management Studio - cannot connect to DB

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I managed to set up SQL Server Express.

I can perfectly connect to it using a Python script with settings:

```
server="myserver.example.de", user="mydomain\myuser", pass="secret..."
```

It connects to port 1433 on the named server and everything is fine.

Now I try using SQL Server Management Studio with the same settings:

```
connect to: Database Engine
server: as above
using "SQL Server Authentication"
user and password as above
```

Then I get :

> Error Number: 18456
> Severity: 14
> State: 1

I already searched for solutions, most of them telling me to allow "Windows and SQL Server authentication" on the server - but: it works in Python, so it should not be a server misconfiguration?

I also tried to set `Address=tcp:1.2.3.4,1433` in options, but that does not help.

So how do I get SQL Server Management Studio to get the connection right?

Thanks in advance, emmwie

Comment: Will you be created as a contained database user rather than at server level? If so you will need to go into "options" on the connection dialogue and the "connection properties" tab and enter the database name there

Comment: Try to specify `server=.\SQLEXPRESS` or `(local)\SQLEXPRESS` in SSMS; the `SQLEXPRESS` is the default instance name - I'm surprised you didn't have to specify that in the Python connection string....

Comment: `mydomain\myuser` means Windows Authentication, which in SSMS would not have a password, you just need to be logged in as that user.

Comment: @marc_s I nailed the port to 1433 - so it's not necessary to provide \SQLEXPRESS

Comment: @Charlieface: I am on MYLAPTOP\SOMEUSER - how can I be logged in as otherdomain\otheruser?

Comment: That's exactly my point: `otherdomain\otheruser` is not a SQL login, it's a Windows login. Therefore if you want to access SQL Server using it then you need to be logged in as that user, you cannot pass it as a username using `user="otherdomain\otheruser"`, instead you just do `Trusted_Connection=yes`. What is happening is that you haven't specified it, so SQL Server is looking for a SQL username called `otherdomain\otheruser` and not finding it. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14268846/python-pyodbc-connect-to-sql-server-2008-db-by-ip-with-trusted-connection

Answer (score -2):

Yep you right,

if your Phyton connection in have "trustedconnection = true",

Sql Management studio connection screen,

Options>Trust Server Certificate (check)

Comment: `Trust Server Certificate` why? There is no indication that there is a TLS problem with certificates here (it's a Login Failed error due to incorrect creds, which you wouldn't get if TLS failed before that). To top it off, if there was a TLS issue then `Trust Server Certificate` is a bad idea, best thing to do is to get a good certificate.